# How can i add different text every 2nd DAY?

Tags: javascript

I want to write off different text on Monday and Tuesday

```
 function updateSubmitButtonState() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var day = currentTime.getDay();
  var isWeekend = (day === 6) || (day === 0);
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
```

This day is not working but i dont know why, how can i do this?(Just the hour and minutes work)

````
 if ( 'day' == 1 ) ```//this is monday//
((hours == 10 && minutes >= 30) 
    || (hours == 11 && minutes <= 30)) {
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'basbas'( day == 6 )
  }
````

This 'day' is not working but i dont know why, how can i do this?

````
 else if ( day == 2 ) ``` // this is tuesday//
((hours == 10 && minutes >= 30) 
    || (hours == 11 && minutes <= 30)) {
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'asdasd'( day == 6 )
````

Comment: OK, im a beginner. I meaned  else if ( day == 2 ) and  else if ( day == 1)

Comment: Maybe you should post what you really have ... But the first comment still stands. Notice also, that the parenthesing is off in both conditions (`||` expressions are not included in conditions) .

Comment: Fk. If i check it on Monday at 10:30-11:30, i want to see: basbas, but if i check it on Tuesday at 10:30-11:30, i want to see: asdasd. The code is wrong ikr, but i hope u understand what i want.

Comment: Yes, I can understand what you want your code to do. But on which possible condition the string "day" would be equal to the number `1`? And include the other conditions in the if condition too, currently they're outside, and the code block is executed in all cases, in both `if`s.

Comment: Actually i dont really know that, i'm said i am a beginner. Can u write the code right?